# Como aumentar espessura das barras em Chart.js?

Tags: react, chartjs

Estou usando o chart.js no react e gostaria que as barras do meu gráfico ficassem mais espessas, sem se amontoarem. A seguir meu componente que renderiza o gráfico:

```
import React from 'react';
import { HorizontalBar } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import './teste.css'

const BarChart = () => {
    return (
        <div className="caps">
            <HorizontalBar 
                data = {{
                    labels: [
                        'Direito', 'Engenharia Civil', 'Ciência da Computação',
                        'Engenharia Elétrica', 'Geografia', 'Ciências Biológicas',
                        'Nutrição', 'Farmácia', 'Enfermagem', 'Matemática', 'História',
                        'Medicina', 'Design', 'Química', 'Administração',
                        'Engenharia de Petróleo', 'Arte e Mídia', 'Letras', 'Estatística',
                        'Engenharia Ambiental', 'Psicologia', 'Engenharia de Alimentos',
                        'Engenharia Mecânica', 'Física', 'Filosofia', 'Engenharia Florestal',
                        'Engenharia Agrícola', 'Engenharia Química', 'Engenharia de Produção',
                        'Pedagogia', 'Ciências Sociais', 'Arquitetura e Urbanismo', 'Agronomia',
                        'Odontologia', 'Meteorologia', 'Medicina Veterinária',
                        'Ciências Econômicas', 'Engenharia de Minas', 'Engenharia de Materiais',
                        'Engenharia de Biotecnologia e Bioprocessos', 'Ciências Contábeis',
                        'Gestão Pública', 'Engenharia de Biossistemas', 'Comunicação Social'
                ],

                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: "Quantidade",
                            data: [
                                138, 128, 114, 112, 99, 92, 90, 82, 73, 71, 66, 63, 53, 46,
                                38, 37, 34, 25, 25, 25, 24, 24, 12, 10, 9, 8, 8, 7, 7, 6, 5,
                                5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1
                            ],
                            backgroundColor: '#EEAD2D',
                            barThickness: 'flex',
                        },
                    ],

            
                }}
                height = {1000}
                width = {400}
                options = {{
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,

                    layout: {
                        padding: 60,
                    },

                    legend: {
                        display: true,
                    },

                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        padding: 10,
                        text: "Nº de Respondentes",
                        fontSize: 25,
                    },

                    scales: {
                        yAxes:[
                            {
                                gridLines: {
                                    color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
                                },

                                ticks: {
                                    beginAtZero: true
                                },
                            },
                        ],

                        xAxes:[
                            {
                                display: false,
                                gridLines: {
                                    color: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
                                },
                            }
                        ],

                    },

                }}
            />
        </div>
    )
};

export default BarChart;
```

Reparem que a propriedade `barThickness`, dentro de `datasets`, está com o valor `flex`. Ao mudar esse valor para `40`, por exemplo, notem que as barras engrossam, mas se amontoam umas sobre as outras. Como deixar as barras mais espessas sem que se sobreponham?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá.

Para modificar a espessura das barras, você pode estar utilizando o **barPercentage**. Ele já entrega por padrão a espessura **.9**. Vai ficar assim:

```
scales: {
   yAxes:[
      {
         barPercentage: .2,
         gridLines: {
            color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
         },
         ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
         },
      },
   ],
   xAxes:[
      {
         display: false,
         gridLines: {
            color: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
         },
      }
   ],
},
```

Se quiser em seguida dar uma melhorada no espaçamento entre as categorias, você pode simplesmente aumentar a altura do gráfico, em **height**. O barPercentage sempre vai levar em consideração o tamanho do gráfico.

Mais um adendo: pode-se utilizar o categoryPercentage, que define o tamanho que a barra ocupa na categoria, e o barPercentage irá ocupar esse espaço. Ou seja, se definir **barPercentage: .5** e o **categoryPercentage: 1**, a barra irá ter o tamanho do metade que foi definida pelo categoryPercentage. E no caso de **barPercentage: 1**, irá ocupar o espaço definido pelo categoryPercentage. Só lembrando de novo, essas opções já vem com um valor padrão. Aqui está o link para a [documentação](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.7.2/charts/bar.html#barpercentage-vs-categorypercentage).

Segue um exemplo aplicado no meu [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/chart-js-732hn?file=/src/components/Chart.js).

Espero ter te ajudado ;D